# Child(wpf usercontrol) calling a function from Parent(winForm)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have Form1 (parent) and it has an elementHost (WPF usercontrol). Now, I want that WPF usercontrol to call a function from its parent or pass value/data. Simple as that.

This is the code I'm using but the program is always crashing..

**Form1:**

```
public void samp()
{
 MessageBox.Show("Sample");
}
```

**WPF userControl:**

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

public void test()
{
 frm1.samp();
}
```

Is it possible for the child to access it's parent directly?

Comment: "the program is always crashing"? What error are you getting?

Comment: No, it doesnt run. I need to restart VS. And it always give 800,000K+ in Task Manager(Processes)

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem as you described: [see this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3169795/StackOverflow/WpfApplication_Japs%20Asuncion.zip) but it seems to work for me. Maybe you can upload your solution somewhere?

Comment: So you used Form1 as wpf, what I made is a WindowForm..But your code works with me well, But i think it only does calling a function not to pass data or some values or im just missing something. wait ill upload so you can see. thanks btw

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?nb2igqang5t2a9k here it is

Comment: that sample is not crashing for me, and the messagebox is shown

Comment: yes its working.. because I used your code here.Now the only thing is not fine is that I can't pass value to Label in Form1.

Answer (score 4):

This program **can't** work! You create a new Form1 in your Wpf usercontrol. Form1 contains this usercontrol... So this is an endless loop!

You have to cast the `Parent` property of the elementhost hosting your WPF usercontrol to `Form1`, then you can call your function, like this:

```
HwndSource wpfHandle = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
if (wpfHandle != null)
{
    ElementHost host = System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(wpfHandle.Handle) as ElementHost;
    if (host != null)
    {
        Form1 form1 = host.Parent as Form1;
        if (form1 != null)
        {
            form1.samp();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on where the instantiation of Form1 takes place. If it's in the constructor of the WPF UserControl (ElementHost.Child) then it's infinte (because on the creation of Form1 a new WPF USerControl will be created and so on...). When having a button on the WPF UserControl that (OnClick) creates a Form1 and calls the public method, I don't see the problem...

Comment: Its not an endless loop. It would only be an endless loop if `void test()` in is example would be called while initializing, but its not.

Comment: @JapsAsuncion: I've edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: @RonSijm and JoepGreuter: We cannot be asured wether it's an endless loop or not, because we don't see the whole code.

Comment: He posted what should be the "whole code" as comment into the first post. That's not an endless loop either. Besides, an endless loop would not crash visual studio to desktop, but would cause a stackoverflow or something

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enject a parental instance into your WPF control. Then having that reference you can manipulate with it.